# Validating queue messages

Tags: java, smtp, ibm-mq, ftp-client

I am inserting messages in a queue using WebSphere MQ tool using java code. While entering the text it will store the message in the queue. I want to validate while inserting messages whether

1.the queue exists or not

2.Is there any channel error

3.Port number mismatch

4.host address error

I want to capture these errors and store it in a text file with time stamp and service in error log.

Help me how to do it.

Menu insertion of messages in queue

[Menu based insertion of messages in queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrcCb.jpg)

[Message inserted in Websphere MQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3kDt.jpg)

public class QueueMessage 
{
     public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

```
private MQQueueManager _queueManager = null;
public int port = 1413;
public String hostname = "192.168.100.120";
public String channel = "QM_HOME.Q_LOCAL";
public String qManager = "QM_HOME";
public String inputQName = "Q_LOCAL_END";
public String outputQName = "Q_LOCAL_END";

public QueueMessage()
{
    super();
}

public void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    // Set up MQ environment
    MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;
    System.out.println("HOST :"+hostname);
    MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
    MQEnvironment.port = port;
    System.out.println("init");
}

public void selectQMgr() throws MQException 
{

    _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);

}


public void write() throws MQException {

    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
    try {
        MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions,
                null, // default q manager
                null, // no dynamic q name
                null); // no alternate user id

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        System.out
                .println("MQWrite v1.0 connected and ready for input, terminate with ^Z\n\n");
        // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text in UTF format..
        MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
        sendmsg.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        sendmsg.feedback = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
        sendmsg.messageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
        sendmsg.replyToQueueName = "QM_LOCAL_END";
        sendmsg.replyToQueueManagerName = qManager;

        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the
        String line = null; 



        System.out.print("Enter your Message: ");
        line = sc.nextLine();

        sendmsg.clearMessage();
        sendmsg.messageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
        sendmsg.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
        sendmsg.writeString(line);
        // put the message on the queue
        queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);

        System.out.println("Message inserted: " + line);
        queue.close();
        _queueManager.disconnect();

        // same
        // as MQPMO_DEFAULT constant



    }

    catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex) {
        System.out.println(mqex);
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println("An MQ IO error occurred : " + ioex);

    }
}

private void While(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked.  The tool shown appears to be MQ Explorer and you would not be able to get to the message entry screen if the queue does not exist.  You would not be able to see the queue list if MQ Explorer had not already connected, in which case host, port and channel must be correct.

Comment: You say you're using Java code - could you show us your Java code? I'm not sure what the MQ Explorer screen shots have to do with your Java code?

Answer (score 1):

> using java code

Standard Java coding - you simply catch the MQException.

```
try
{
   _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, myHashTable);
}
catch (MQException e)
{
   System.err.println("Completion Code=" + e.completionCode + " Reason Code=" + e.reasonCode);
}
```

Everything about MQ is documented in the [MQ Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ/com.ibm.mq.helphome.doc/product_welcome_wmq.htm).  All of the MQ/Java classes are documented - i.e. [MQQueueManager class](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html)

The #1 rule to remember is that object names (queues, channels, etc) are case sensitive.  Rule #2 is that MQ is NOT a database.  Rule #3, make sure your application logs ALL 'Exceptions'.

> 1.the queue exists or not

Reason code of 2085 (MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME)

> 2.Is there any channel error

Reason code of 2009 (MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN)

> 3.Port number mismatch

Reason code of 2059 (MQRC_Q_MGR_NOT_AVAILABLE)

> 4.host address error

Reason code of 2538 (MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code,it works fine while inserting messages, I want to capture the errors if the message is not stored in Websphere MQ. And to store the errors in a log file

public class QueueMessage 
{
     public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

```
private MQQueueManager _queueManager = null;
public int port = 1413;
public String hostname = "192.168.100.120";
public String channel = "QM_HOME.Q_LOCAL";
public String qManager = "QM_HOME";
public String inputQName = "Q_LOCAL_END";
public String outputQName = "Q_LOCAL_END";

public QueueMessage()
{
    super();
}

public void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    // Set up MQ environment
    MQEnvironment.hostname = hostname;
    MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
    MQEnvironment.port = port;

}

public void selectQMgr() throws MQException 
{
    _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(qManager);
}


public void write() throws MQException {

    int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
    try {
        MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions,
                null, // default q manager
                null, // no dynamic q name
                null); // no alternate user id

        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        System.out
                .println("MQWrite v1.0 connected and ready for input, terminate with ^Z\n\n");
        // Define a simple MQ message, and write some text in UTF format..
        MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
        sendmsg.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
        sendmsg.feedback = MQC.MQFB_NONE;
        sendmsg.messageType = MQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;
        sendmsg.replyToQueueName = "QM_LOCAL_END";
        sendmsg.replyToQueueManagerName = qManager;

        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the
        String line = null; // defaults,

        System.out.print("Enter your Message: ");
        line = sc.nextLine();
        sendmsg.clearMessage();
        sendmsg.messageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
        sendmsg.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
        sendmsg.writeString(line);
        // put the message on the queue
        queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
        System.out.println("Message inserted: " + line);
        queue.close();
        _queueManager.disconnect();

        // same
        // as MQPMO_DEFAULT constant

    }

    catch (com.ibm.mq.MQException mqex) {
        System.out.println(mqex);
    } catch (java.io.IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println("An MQ IO error occurred : " + ioex);

    }
}

private void While(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Humm.  That code looks familiar - oh wait, you downloaded my [MQWrite](http://capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html) sample code.

First, you should get away from using MQEnvironment class.  It is designed for basic single-threaded applications.  You should put the information in a HashTable and pass that to the MQQueueManager class.

Secondly, adding logging is a basic Java programming thing. You can use the builtin logger or use a 3rd party class.  I have used Log4J for many, many years.

So, here is MQWrite2 Java/MQ sample code that sets the connection information in a HashTable and uses Log4J as the logger.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  MQWrite2
 *
 * Description
 *  This java class will connect to a queue manager and
 *  and write a message to a queue.
*
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -h 127.0.0.1 -p 1414 -c MY.TEST.EXIT -m MQA1 -q TEST.Q1
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix, Capitalware Inc.
 */
public class MQWrite2
{
   private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MQWrite2.class.getName());
   private Hashtable<String, String> params = null;
   private Hashtable<String, Object> mqht = null;
   private String qMgrName;
   private String outputQName;

   /**
    * The constructor
    */
   public MQWrite2()
   {
      super();
      logger.info("MQWrite2 is now starting.");
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      boolean b = params.containsKey("-h") && params.containsKey("-p") &&
                  params.containsKey("-c") && params.containsKey("-m") &&
                  params.containsKey("-q");
      if (b)
      {
         try
         {
            Integer.parseInt((String) params.get("-p"));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            b = false;
         }
      }

      return b;
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ variables.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         qMgrName = (String) params.get("-m");
         outputQName = (String) params.get("-q");

         mqht = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

         mqht.put(CMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, params.get("-c"));
         mqht.put(CMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, params.get("-h"));

         try
         {
            mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(params.get("-p")));
         }
         catch (NumberFormatException e)
         {
            mqht.put(CMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(1414));
         }

         // I don't want to see MQ exceptions at the console.
         MQException.log = null;
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Connect, open queue, write a message, close queue and disconnect.
    *
    */
   private void testReceive()
   {
      int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
      MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
      MQQueueManager _qMgr = null;
      MQQueue queue = null;
      MQMessage sendMsg = null;
      String line = "This is a test message.";

      try
      {
         _qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qMgrName, mqht);
         queue = _qMgr.accessQueue(outputQName, openOptions);

         sendMsg = new MQMessage();
         sendMsg.messageId = CMQC.MQMI_NONE;
         sendMsg.correlationId = CMQC.MQCI_NONE;
         sendMsg.writeString(line);
         // put the message on the queue
         queue.put(sendMsg, pmo);
         logger.info("MQWrite2 Message inserted: " + line);
      }
      catch (MQException mqex)
      {
         logger.error("MQWrite2 MQException CC=" +mqex.completionCode + " : RC=" + mqex.reasonCode);
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         logger.error("MQWrite2 IOException " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            if (queue != null)
               queue.close();
         }
         catch (MQException mqex2)
         {
            logger.error("MQWrite2 MQException CC=" +mqex2.completionCode + " : RC=" + mqex2.reasonCode);
         }
         finally
         {
            try
            {
               if (_qMgr != null)
                  _qMgr.disconnect();
            }
            catch (MQException mqex3)
            {
               logger.error("MQWrite2 MQException CC=" +mqex3.completionCode + " : RC=" + mqex3.reasonCode);
            }
         }
      }

      logger.info("MQWrite2 is now ending.");
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MQWrite2 write = new MQWrite2();

      try
      {
         write.init(args);
         write.testReceive();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         System.out.println("Usage: java MQWrite2 -h host -p port -c channel -m QueueManagerName -q QueueName");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

And here is the 'log4j.properties' file that goes with the code:

```
#
# stdout
#
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
#
# MQWrite
#
log4j.category.MQWrite2=DEBUG, mqwrite, stdout
#log4j.category.MQWrite2=INFO, mqwrite, stdout
# "mqwrite" appender writes to a file
log4j.appender.mqwrite=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.mqwrite.File=log/MQWrite.log
log4j.appender.mqwrite.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.mqwrite.MaxBackupIndex=9
log4j.appender.mqwrite.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.mqwrite.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p - %m%n
#log4j.appender.mqwrite.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %p (%F:%M:%L) - %m%n
```

Make sure you create a 'log' directory under the directory where you run the code from or else it will throw an error like:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log\MQWrite.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Pssst.  You can read and download from here: http://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=3885